# Is there anyway to specify filters for an xlink:href in svg?

Tags: svg, symbols, xlink

Is there anyway to specify filters for an xlink:href in an svg?  For example, I only want to reference 's from a specific parent/svg.  If I have multiple svgs on that page, and both happen to contain an element with the same id, it seems that the xlink:href will always reference the first instance, regardless of which svg the xlink:href is.

For example,

...

```
<html>
 <div id="div1">
     <!-- first svg -->
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

     <symbol id="car" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
         <circle.../>    
     </symbol>
```

```
<div id="div2">
   <!-- second svg -->
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

       <symbol id="car" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
           <rect.../>    
       </symbol>
```

...

```
<!-- This will show as a circle, instead of a rectangle -->

    <use xlink:href="#car" .../>
    </svg>
 </html>`
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to use the unique div id's as reference.  For example,

```
<use xlink:href="#div2 #car" .../>
```

Comment: ids must be unique so your file is invalid. And once you make the ids unique you won't have this problem any more.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  Providing unique ids do work, and I understand the rationale.  The design also parallels anchor tags..  However, from another perspective, especially in terms of dynamic content, it seems limiting that you need to factor in the entire document, and there's no way to use xlink:hrefs within the scope of it's svg.